# Difference between intervertebral and vertebral foramina

Tags: human-biology, human-anatomy, vertebrates

In the human spine, what is the difference between intervertebral and vertebral foramina? Is it just a matter of perspective and do they refer to the same thing or are they different?

Answer (score 5):

They are actually different.

[image]
<sub>(source: [emory.edu](https://www.emory.edu/ANATOMY/AnatomyManual/38.jpg))</sub>

**INTERVERTEBRAL FORAMINA** is actually spaces between adjacent vertebrae which gives *passage for spinal nerves to exit*.

Whereas, **VERTEBRAL FORAMINA** forms *vertebral canal.*

### Source:

[Organization of the Nervous System: An introduction for students in the Human Anatomy Course](http://www.physiology.emory.edu/)